# How to rewrite MVC Actions & properties to ASP Core MVVM Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, razor-pages

In the new release of ASP CORE 2.0 last month, they introduced Razor Pages, this has me in a loop since the old controller & the model frpm MVC are missing from ASP CORE 2 Razor pages.

My understanding from this [page](https://stackify.com/asp-net-razor-pages-vs-mvc/) is that we get default binding of the properties using a `[BindProperty] attribute` outside the Action/Method!!!!, this is because its moved to an `MVVM framework` as opposed to `MVC` framework.

1. Question: While trying to rewrite the traditional actions, since there are no controllers, how to move to the code to the new RazorPages MVVM framework, i.e. **and where and how to bind the properties, and actions/handlers?**
2. Since the properties are *not* in the signature, **how does the action/handler know which properties were passed to it from the View/Razor Page?**

What is the PageModel?

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel // what is this pagemodel, is it new or the same old model?
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _db;

    public CreateModel(AppDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; } // why is the property outside?

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _db.Customers.Add(Customer);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor pages is from my understanding pretty much a replacement for the old asp.net forms where you simply have a page with logic. A bit like how php does things.

If you create a page, let's say `Pages/Index2.cshtml` you should also create (or it may be created for you in Visual Studio) a "code-behind" file called `Pages/Index2.cshtml.cs` for example.

```
// The page file

@page
@using RazorPages
@model IndexModel2

<h2>Separate page model</h2>
<p>
    @Model.Message
</p>


// The code-behind file

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System;

namespace RazorPages
{
    public class IndexModel2 : PageModel
    {
        public string Message { get; private set; } = "PageModel in C#";

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message += $" Server time is { DateTime.Now }";
        }
    }
}
```

You can still have models and initialize them in the code-behind file. But if you want controllers, I would suggest you **do not** use razor pages and just use the classical mvc. You can create a new project with it, just don't choose razor pages from the template. **You certainly do not need to create a razor pages project. It is just an option**. I personally do not really use it since I think is prone for one to repeat code since every code-behind file is just valid for one page afaik.

> What is the PageModel?

A pagemodel is simply the code-behind file that does server side logic for your specific page.

I am not sure exactly what you are asking for, you bind models like any other razor page and properties in the code-behind class. The model is the code-behind file in my example.

> how does the action/handler know which properties were passed to it from the View/Razor Page?

The action handler knows it by you specifying it in the razor page:
`<input asp-for="Customer.Name" />`

Please read more about Razor Pages here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio

Comment: thanks for the response, I was wondering where do the actions go? especially for the form submits/Ajax calls... everything seems tied to the OnPOST handler... do I need to build my own custom router... seems like a step backwards. Wondering why should I move to this, or when should this model be considered

Comment: @transformer Well, every server action is probably best to place in each pages model. Since every page has it's own logic, you cannot really reuse logic in an easy way like with a controller.

I think you should use razorpages for projects that maybe previously used classic asp forms and/or for smaller projects where you don't need shared logic between pages. OF course, you could still create some service classes and use it the same. But I would say go with classic MVC and not razorpages if you're not certain on why you would choose razorpages.

Comment: "But if you want controllers, I would suggest you do not use razor pages" -- You can use controllers alongside Razor Pages. I do this if I want API-style URIs that don't necessarily relate to a specific page. You could even mix MVC views with Razor Pages if you really wanted to. Razor Pages only relationship to Web Forms is that they're both MVVM, they have none of the other Web Forms baggage (like viewstate, the page lifecycle, asp controls, single form limit, etc).